# How to install QGIS 2.14.9 along with python-2.7.5 in rhel 8?

Tags: python, qgis, rhel7, rhel8

My Application requires QGIS-2.14.9 and python 2.7.5.
I was able to set environment in rhel7 by creating a local repository and copying some the required  RPM's in it and it is taking the remaining RPMs from the "rhel7-server-repo". I am now migrating to rhel8 but I am not able set up the same environment. It was throwing some errors while installing some of the RPM's as their dependent libraries are not present in local-repo or rhel8 server repo. Even If I download and place the dependent files that it was asking, it is asking for some other files and this process is endless.

Please explain how to fix this issue

Comment: You could solve this by putting your application and its dependencies into a container (e.g., using Docker), but containerizing GUI applications like QGIS can be tricky.

Comment: It is probably easier to update the app to use QGis 3 and python 3